# "No Value given for one or more parameters" with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010

when I want to retrieve date from access , I get an exception error "No Value given for one or more parameters" at **cmd1.ExecuteReader**. This is my code

```
void checking_fields()
    {

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select movie_id from event", oc);
        OleDbDataReader ol = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select [open date],[close date] from event", oc);
        OleDbDataReader ol1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (ol1.Read())
        {
            if (ol1.GetValue(0).ToString() == dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") || 
                ol1.GetValue(1).ToString() == dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                goto abc;
        }
        ol.Read();

        if (textBox1.Text.Equals(ol.GetString(0)))
            label8.Text = "ID already exists";
        else
        {
            insert_database();
            clear();
            this.Close();
        }
        abc:  label8.Text = "Open date or Close date already assigned";
        }
```

These are the properties of open date and close date

required:no,
indexed:yes(no duplicates),
ime_mode:no_control,
text_align:center,
show_date_picker:for_dates

since I am new to c#, please help me

Comment: Your second GetValue is ol instead of ol1

Comment: did you opened the connection?

Comment: yes I opened and closed the connection.

Comment: Do you really have `goto abc;` inside the `while` loop ? I think the spaces in the column names `open date` is the culprit

Comment: you should put all your code so we can help please

Comment: Can you confirm if you have `event` table in the database you are connecting too, seems likely that its not there ( since `[open date]` brackets helps in taking care of spaces in column names)

Comment: I confirmed that all the tables in database is connected... please help me

Comment: You don't have any parameters in your query. This means that one or more of your field names `Open Date` or `Close Date` didn't exist in your table `event`

Comment: @Steve has it correct.  That particular error means that of the 3 things in the query, 2 columns and a table name...one or more of them does not exist.  Check your spelling.  Check your capitalization.  Check your spaces. etc etc...

Comment: @Nevyn, yes, but the table `event` should exist because the first query has no problem. So we have only two possible cause of errors. The two field names.

Comment: thanks @steve. you are correct. I did the spelling mistake 'close dat' instead of 'close date' in my database. Sorry all.

Comment: If you don't mind, please, mark as accepted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any parameters in your query.
This means that one or more of your field names
`Open Date` or `Close Date`
didn't exist in your table event

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you haven't opened the connection:

```
void checking_fields()
{

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select movie_id from event", oc);
oc.open();

    OleDbDataReader ol1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (ol1.Read())
    {
        if (ol1.GetValue(0).ToString() == dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") || 
            ol1.GetValue(1).ToString() == dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            goto abc;
    }
oc.close();

    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select [open date],[close date] from event", oc);
    oc.open();
    OleDbDataReader ol = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ol.Read(); // consider revising that section

    if (textBox1.Text.Equals(ol.GetString(0)))
        label8.Text = "ID already exists";
    else
    {
        insert_database();
        clear();
        this.Close();
    }
    abc:  label8.Text = "Open date or Close date already assigned";
    }
```

And I made some modifications, I executed one reader ,closed it, before executing the second one.

Comment: I already open the connection in the calling function. this code gives the error "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open".

Comment: @MohanRajK I suggest that you use sql profiler and check what is the query executed against the database

Comment: @Mohan Raj K, The main difference between Boomer and your code is that he opens and closes the connection for each command. You don't.